# Problem with overriding compareTo method in subclass

Tags: java, comparable, compareto

I am creating subclass and have some class elements inside it. Now I want to override compareTo method from super class and use variables from subclass as argument in new compareTo method but I get error saying that the argument for compareTo method must be the same as in the superclass.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Solutions that I tried are:

1)just simply to write new method in subclass (not to override method from super class)
2) create new compareTo method in superclass with arguments I want

this way program is working but I feel like that is not the correct way to fix this problem

Anyone can suggest something or give advice about this?

Comment: Include the code of the superclass (the key element is the implements line. Is it `implements Comparator`, or `implements Comparable<Foobar>`, etc), and the code of your class: Both the `compareTo` line as well as your extends/implements line.

Comment: This is one of those cases where generics aren't going to prevent having to cast. See https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.sql/share/classes/java/sql/Timestamp.java#L453 for an example how it was done in the JDK. An alternative is to just cast and let the JVM throw a `ClassCastException` if the type doesn't match.

Comment: @RobSpoor that is most likely (the question needs more detail) misleading. Given the requirement that comparison impls are commutative, what OP wants is impossible, and generics-casting doesn't make the impossible possible.

Comment: @RobSpoor see my answer which shows why what OP wants is in fact impossible.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I disagree that it's impossible. However, the signature will indeed have to be `compareTo(Parent p)`, not `compareTo(Child c)`. The first line of that method could be `Child c = (Child) p`, which would give a `ClassCastException` if not provided with a `Child` instance. While you indeed lose commutativity when mixing `Parent` and `Child` instances, comparison would still work if only comparing `Child` instances.

Comment: You've defined the word 'work' differently. Your definition evidently does not include 'adheres to the contract', and means Child instances are no longer interchangible with Parent instances. In specific scenarios (namely, when you don't need this) then you could say it 'works', but it's a ticking timebomb; you have to put in the javadoc something like `<strong>NB: Do not use instances of Child as Parents in any context where natural order is relevant as they violate the Comparable contract - bugs that take DAYS to find let alone fix will ensue! Caveat Emptor!</strong>`. You can, but, yich.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am creating subclass and have some class elements inside it.

Okay.

> Now I want to override compareTo method from super class and use variables from subclass

Impossible.

Comparable is a 'contract interface' - you can't *just* implement the methods; you aren't "done" when you have implemented every method and they compile and (appear to) run without throwing exceptions: The documentation states additional rules you need to adhere to that the compiler cannot check. The fact that the compiler cannot check that you adhere to these rules means your code compiles. However, your code is still broken. ("It compiles" does not mean "It is correct", after all).

One of the rules in the contract is that comparison operations are commutative and associative: if `a.compareTo(b)` returns a negative number, then `b.compareTo(a)` **must** return a positive number, (and if one returns `0` so must the other) and vice versa. If you fail to adhere to the contract, crazy stuff happens. For example, you create a `TreeSet` and things end up out of order and this kind of code can start printing `false`:

```java
TreeSet<YourBrokenItem> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.add(a);
set.add(b);
System.out.println(set.contains(a)); // prints false?
```

However, adhering to the contract (the commutativity) rule **is not possible** when you subclass and want to override definitions. Let's make it practical:

```java
class Parent implements Comparable<Parent> {
  int x;

  /** Sort on x */
  @Override public int compareTo(Parent other) {
    return Integer.compare(x, other.x);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent implements Comparable<Child> {
  int y;

  /** Sort on x first; if those are equal, sort on y */
  @Override public int compareTo(Child other) {
    int c = Integer.compare(x, other.x);
    if (c != 0) return c;
    return Integer.compare(y, other.y);
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't work for two reasons: [A] it can't be made to compile, and [B] even if you voodoo magic that away with generics casting, the code breaks the contract. And always will, you can't fix [B].

So instead of delving deep on generics and working around it (which you can), it is a moot point - B cannot be worked around, so what you want is impossible, therefore there is no point explaining how to hack around so that the compiler accepts it.

The reason it's not possible is the commutativity rule. Let's consider 3 instances:

```
Parent p = new Parent(10);
Child c = new Child(10, 5);
Child d = new Child(10, 20);
```

Your intent is very clearly that this happens:

```java
System.out.println(c.compareTo(d)); // prints -1
System.out.println(d.compareTo(c)); // prints +1
```

However, what happens when p is involved? Remember, `Child` says that it is a subtype of `Parent` which means an instance of Child **can do everything an instance of Parent can do, *and* more**. One thing Parent can do, is compare itself to another instance of Parent. And instances of Child are also instances of Parent, so, you can compare a Parent to a Child and vice versa. Hence, `p.compareTo(a)` is valid. Similarly, you can make a `new TreeSet<Parent>()` and you can of course invoke `.add(new Child())` on that. After all, instances of Child are definitely also instances of Parent, that's what subclassing means.

Thus:

```
p.compareTo(c); // This returns 0 - and you can't stop that from happening!
p.compareTo(d); // so does this

// thus, given the above, this:
c.compareTo(d);
// MUST, BY CONTRACT, return 0!
```

Hence, what you want? Impossible. The contract of comparable forbids it.

Effectively, with Comparable, you 'pick a level' and comparability is defined strictly on that level, and subclasses cannot change that. Whatever type in your type hierarchy decides to `implements Comparable`, that's the level. They set the baseline of the natural comparison for those things **and subclasses cannot modify how that works at all** without breaking the contract.

What you probably want is to forget about natural order and use comparators instead. Every system that works on natural order (such as `TreeSet`, or `list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())` or `Collections.sort(list)` or `Arrays.binarySearch`, and so on), *also* has an overloaded variant that accepts a `Comparator<T>`.

You *CAN* make a custom comparator that compares, specifically, children. You can even make a custom comparator that compares children *and* parents if you define the comparison operation properly (meaning, there is a complete order). For example, by saying that given equal `x` values, any `new Parent()` instance will always sort before any `new Child()`, regardless of Child's y value:

```
Comparator<Parent> myCustomComparator = (a, b) -> {
  int c = Integer.compare(a.x, b.x);
  if (c != 0) return c; // x isn't equal so it controls.
  if (a instanceof Child && !(b instanceof Child)) return +1;
  if (!(a instanceof Child) && b instanceof Child) return -1;
  if (!(a instanceof Child) && !(b instanceof Child)) return 0;
  int y1 = ((Child) a).y, y2 = ((Child) b).y;
  return Integer.compare(y1, y2);
};

TreeSet<Parent> myAwesomeSelfSortingSet = new TreeSet<Parent>(myCustomComparator);
// and voila.
```

Comment: Well said.  I was getting ready to mention the violation of polymorphism;  you explained it better than I could have.